# Contact form disappears in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a contact form at the following link.  Looks fine in Chrome and Internet Explorer, however on Firefox it disappears completely.  Any idea what is causing it to do that?

http://www.brightonorient.com/shop.html?page=shop.ask&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=775&category_id=22

*UPDATE*

Adding float: left to the fieldset seemed to work.

Comment: Hmm. Running it through the W3C HTML Validator, you have a few errors, the least of which appears to be a malformed style tag: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brightonorient.com%2Fshop.html%3Fpage%3Dshop.ask%26flypage%3Dflypage.tpl%26product_id%3D775%26category_id%3D22&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Thanks mate, added float:left and it seemed to work. The fieldset looked closed to me?

Answer (score 2):

Your form isn't properly closed, try closing the fieldset, also running through the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/) produces errors, fix those first and you'll have a better idea.

Different browsers are less strict (or just more intelligent depending which way you look at it)when it comes to html markup or omitting closing tags.

Comment: Thanks mate, added float:left and it seemed to work.  The fieldset looked closed to me?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed the fieldset tag. Insert it before the closing form tag.

Comment: Thanks mate, added float:left and it seemed to work. The fieldset looked closed to me?

Comment: You have no closing fieldset tag.

Comment: Whilst your original problem wasn't due to the fieldset tag, you really do not have a closing fieldset tag. View your source code, not the developer view where the browser may fill in missing gaps. It's poor coding practice and potentially may cause problems in older browsers.

Comment: Anyway, do as others have told you. Run the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.brightonorient.com%2Fshop.html%3Fpage%3Dshop.ask%26flypage%3Dflypage.tpl%26product_id%3D775%26category_id%3D22&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and check that your code meets standards.

Answer (score 0):

The error console is showing Error: $() is null

```
$().ready(function() {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
    woahbar_show();
 }, 5000);
});
```